# How to create an array of strings in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm teaching myself C from a book and I am trying to create a crossword puzzle. I need to make an array of strings but keep running into problems. Also, I don't know much about array...

This is the piece of the code:

```
char word1 [6] ="fluffy", word2[5]="small",word3[5]="bunny";

char words_array[3]; /*This is my array*/

char *first_slot = &words_array[0]; /*I've made a pointer to the first slot of words*/

words_array[0]=word1; /*(line 20)Trying to put the word 'fluffy' into the fist slot of the array*/
```

But I keep getting the message:

```
crossword.c:20:16: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

Not sure what is the problem...I have tried to look up how to make an array of strings but with no luck

Any help will be much appreciated,

Sam

Comment: try to study a bit more about arrays http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm .

Comment: By the way - `char word1 [6] ="fluffy"` - "fluffy" is actually 7 characters. In C, a string is terminated with a `\0` - which takes up one extra character.

Comment: `const char* arr[] = { "literal", "string", "pointer", "array"};`, and note the **const**.

Comment: `&words[0]` Er...you don't seem to have a variable `words` at that point. Did you make an error copying your code or leave out something?

Comment: @ArjunShankar Oh yeah I forgot about \0, thanks

Comment: @dmckee Yeah you're right it's suppose to be &words_array[0]

Comment: I guess you are trying to do the following:
const char * const words_array[] = { "fluffy", "small", "bunny"};

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> ```
> words_array[0]=word1;
> ```

`word_array[0]` is a `char`, whereas `word1` is a `char *`. Your character is not able to hold an address.

An array of strings might look like it:

```
char array[NUMBER_STRINGS][STRING_MAX_SIZE];
```

If you rather want an array of pointers to your strings:

```
char *array[NUMBER_STRINGS];
```

And then:

```
array[0] = word1;
array[1] = word2;
array[2] = word3;
```

Maybe you should read [this](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

Answer (score 12):

If you need an array of strings. There are two ways:

**1. Two Dimensional Array of characters**

In this case, you will have to know the size of your strings beforehand. It looks like below:

```
// This is an array for storing 10 strings,
// each of length up to 49 characters (excluding the null terminator).
char arr[10][50];
```

**2. An array of character pointers**

It looks like below:

```
// In this case you have an array of 10 character pointers 
// and you will have to allocate memory dynamically for each string.
char *arr[10];

// This allocates a memory for 50 characters.
// You'll need to allocate memory for each element of the array.
arr[1] = malloc(50 *sizeof(char));
```

Answer (score 9):

The declaration

```
char words_array[3];
```

creates an array of three *characters*. You seem to want to declare an array of character *pointers*:

```
char *words_array[3];
```

---

You have a more serious problem though. The declaration

```
char word1 [6] ="fluffy";
```

creates an array of six character, but you actually tell it to have *seven* character. All strings have an extra character, `'\0'`, that is used to tell the end of the string.

Either declare the array to be of size seven:

```
char word1 [7] ="fluffy";
```

or leave the size out, and the compiler will figure it out by itself:

```
char word1 [] ="fluffy";
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `malloc()` to allocate memory manually:

```
int N = 3;
char **array = (char**) malloc((N+1)*sizeof(char*));
array[0] = "fluffy";
array[1] = "small";
array[2] = "bunny";
array[3] = 0;
```

If you don't know in advance (at coding time) how many strings will be in an array and how lengthy they'll be, this is a way to go. But you'll have to free the memory when it's not used anymore (call `free()`).