# Transform Double Array into a String Array

Tags: c, arrays, string, double

I have a double array a[1] which containing 2 doubles.

```
a[0]=36.78;    
a[1]=45.78;
```

Is it possible to transform them into 2 strings and put them in a string array?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- declare a string array
- convert each item to string within a for loop
- and add each converted item to string array

Answer (score 2):

You can do this to convert double to string:

```
double d = 123456.1234567899;
char s[50];

sprintf(s,"%f", d);
printf("%s\n", s);
```

And then create one string array like this

[How to create array String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15161819/5714463)

And finally you only need to bind this two things

Comment: Use `snprintf` rather than `sprintf`. Avoid using functions that do not let you specify the size of the destination buffer.